# creating a function that reads a file, stores in array, then prints the number of times the words appear in the array

Tags: python, arrays, list, text-files

i want to create a function that will;

- read in a text file , read the file word by word and store the words in an array.
- count the number of occurrences of each word and only store each word once in the array.
- output each word with its number of occurrences displayed beside it.

example:

Text file says: "Frank eats peas eats fries peas"

Will create an array, [Frank, eats, peas, eats, fries, peas]

then, the final product would print;

Frank  1
eats   2
peas   2
fries  1

--

this is what i have so far

```
def countWordsInFile():
    array = []
    array2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    length = len(array)
    fileName = getUserText("Enter the name of the file you want to read array from")
    openFile = openNewFile(fileName,"read")
    i = openFile
    for words in i.read().split():
        array.append(words)
    print(array)

    for i in range(0,length,1):
        count = array.count[i]
        array2.append(count)
    print(array2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary for this, your altered code would look like:

```py
def countWordsInFile():
    words = {}
    fileName = getUserText("Enter the name of the file you want to read array from")
    openFile = openNewFile(fileName,"read")
    for word in openFile.read().split():
        if word not in words:
            words[word] = 1
        else:
            words[word] += 1
    print(words)
```